# reading partitioned parquet record in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, parquet, partition

I have a parquet file partitioned by a date field (YYYY-MM-DD).
How to read the (current date-1 day) records from the file efficiently in Pyspark - please suggest.

PS: I would not like to read the entire file and then filter the records as the data volume is huge.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about this:
Suppose this is the input data and you write out the dataframe partitioned on "date" column:

```
data = [(datetime.date(2022, 6, 12),  "Hello"), (datetime.date(2022, 6, 19), "World")]
schema = StructType([StructField("date", DateType()),StructField("message", StringType())])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('date').parquet('./test')
```

You can read the parquet files associated to a given date with this syntax:

```
spark.read.parquet('./test/date=2022-06-19').show()

# The catch is that the date column is gonna be omitted from your dataframe
+-------+                                                                       
|message|
+-------+
|  World|
+-------+

# You could try adding the date column with lit syntax.
(spark.read.parquet('./test/date=2022-06-19')
 .withColumn('date', f.lit('2022-06-19').cast(DateType()))
 .show()
)
# Output
+-------+----------+
|message|      date|
+-------+----------+
|  World|2022-06-19|
+-------+----------+
```

The more efficient solution is using the delta tables:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('date').format('delta').save('/test')
spark.read.format('delta').load('./test').where(f.col('date') == '2022-06-19').show()
```

The spark engine uses the _delta_log to optimize your query and only reads the parquet files that are applicable to your query. Also, the output will have all the columns:

```
+-------+----------+
|message|      date|
+-------+----------+
|  World|2022-06-19|
+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read it by passing date variable while reading.

This is dynamic code, you nor need to hardcode date, just append it with path

```
>>> df.show()
+-----+-----------------+-----------+----------+
|Sr_No|          User_Id|Transaction|        dt|
+-----+-----------------+-----------+----------+
|    1|paytm 111002203@p|       100D|2022-06-29|
|    2|paytm 111002203@p|        50C|2022-06-27|
|    3|paytm 111002203@p|        20C|2022-06-26|
|    4|paytm 111002203@p|        10C|2022-06-25|
|    5|             null|         1C|2022-06-24|
+-----+-----------------+-----------+----------+

>>> df.write.partitionBy("dt").mode("append").parquet("/dir1/dir2/sample.parquet")

>>> from datetime import date
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> today = date.today()
#Here i am taking two days back date, for one day back you can do (days=1)
>>> yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 2)
>>> two_days_back=yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

>>> path="/di1/dir2/sample.parquet/dt="+two_days_back
>>> spark.read.parquet(path).show()
+-----+-----------------+-----------+
|Sr_No|          User_Id|Transaction|
+-----+-----------------+-----------+
|    2|paytm 111002203@p|        50C|
+-----+-----------------+-----------+
```